# UV Mapping before Applying Modifiers

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to know whether there is a way to UV unwrap your models, before applying modifiers such as mirror and arrays, and have those same meshes share the same space in the UV map, after applying it.

I'm currently hand painting textures, and this would save me a ton of time, if I wouldn't have to retexture a mesh I arrayed 20 times.

Comment: Unwarp it before then don't apply the array modifier.

Comment: Applying the modifiers creates new meshes and geometry, which would need UV unwrapping as well, and I would need to apply the modifiers to complete my models. So, how would I go about solving the problem? Unless if I UV unwrap it before applying the modifiers, Blender is smart enough to know that they share the same space on the UV Map.

I will try it out.

Comment: Tried it out and it works. After you've UV unwrapped the model, when you apply the modifiers, it will also apply the layout of the UV in the same positions as well, thanks question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Yohello 1, I was able to solve the problem. There is no need for a separate round of UV unwrapping, as long as you haven't applied the modifiers.

This means, that if an object has an array, and you UV unwrap before applying the array modifier, then after you apply the array modifier, or any modifier, it will also use the new meshes on the same UV map as the first it was based on.

Comment: It depends on the modifiers and what you need, but most modifiers will try to be smart about generated UV.  Mirror and array modifiers, which you specify, have options to control how they generate UV in the modifier settings.